# inserting a meta box url into jQuery backstretch

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-backstretch

I am working on a new wordpress portfolio website, one of the features using jquery.backstretch.js

I have been able to create the successful code using the following, which includes the direct url to the image:

```
<script>
    $(".feature").backstretch("http://www.matthewgideon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/test.jpg", {
        fade: 1500
    });
</script>
```

I would like to pull the url from a meta box, but my coding does not appear to work. This is what I tried:

```
<script>
    $(".feature").backstretch("<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cd_custom_url', true ); ?>", {
        fade: 1500
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: or the other option I wanted to try was pulling the wordpress page's "featured" image into the backstretch coding

Comment: fixed the issue - had nothing to do with the coding I was trying, I was missing the following code after the navigation:  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

Comment: in the end the following work fine: <script>
    $(".feature").backstretch("<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_cd_custom_url', true ); ?>", {
        fade: 1500
    });
</script>